# If I can prove that my drawing/illustration was constructed from various image references, can't I be prosecuted?

Tags: copyright, data-ownership

**Background:**

For my design work, I sometimes create portraits to illustrate campaigns and other media. In an effort to avoid mis-appropriating someone's likeness, I tend to draw from a collection of unrelated found portraits and previous life-drawings to construct a "unique" portrait. I've always been anxious about ***accidentally*** appropriating the likeness of someone without realizing it. I'm currently living in Ireland. I'm aware that in the field of photography, any persons featured in a photo to be used commercially must sign a model release form in accordance with Copyright and Related Rights Act (Ireland), 2000 and Data Protection Act (Ireland), 1988.

**My Question:**

**If I can prove that my drawing/illustration was "constructed" from a mishmash of various image references, surely I'm not a criminal?** :P

P.S. I haven't posted on the Law stack before so apologies if I haven't provided enough background!

Comment: If you're using a "sterilized" depiction of a person (not taking personally identifiable/distinctive characteristics) you'll generally be fine. If it bares too much a likeness to a celebrity (unlikely) the celebrity may claim that you are using their likeness to promote a product or if it is viewed as something negative (like perhaps some random person resembling the user of an incontinence product ie: adult diapers) and it published specifically in the area they live, they may have a case. Short answer, if you can prove the likeness isn't deliberate, you should be fine.

Comment: Based on your actual wording, is that not the wrong way round?

If it could be proved your illustration was constructed from specific images, you might well be prosecuted.

If it could be shown your image had been constructed from various different images, each and every one of which had been significantly altered, you might be safe.